# Problemas ao iniciar UIImage com caminho da imagem vindo do core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableviewcell, uiimage

Realizei o download de uma imagem, e armazenei em disco. Após o download a classe insere o caminho da imagem no core data, ficando esta string:

```
@"/Users/Tiago/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E103B07-E48E-4740-911C-ECD24E0C3A3F/data/Containers/Data/Application/D17A1BA1-7096-49F9-BDAD-9587B2780715/Documents/54bf3ebf657f6f2c04a81b0b.jpg
"
```

Porém no momento de carregar esta imagem em um UIImage ele é iniciado com nil, como mostrado no código abaixo:

```
// Implementação de uma UITableView.
...

    NSManagedObject *device = [dadosRetornadosDoCoreData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
...
    NSString* stringPath = [device valueForKey:@"imagempath"];
    UIImage* imageNew = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:stringPath];
    [cell.imagemProduto setImage:imageNew];
    return cell;
```

Adicionei uma imagem a vulso no projeto, e carreguei como o código abaixo:

```
UIImage* imageNew = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cloud.png"];
```

E carregou normalmente.

Detalhe: a String que leva até a imagem está vindo do armazenamento do Core Data. Não sei se isso pode afetar na interpretação da String.

Comment: Nem sempre o diretório `Documents` estará no mesmo local, pode alterar em uma atualização do aplicativo, por exemplo. O ideal é você guardar apenas o nome do arquivo e então carregar a imagem montando todo o caminho acrescentado do nome.

Comment: Obrigado, eu vi essa recomendação em outro post. Como posso localizar a pasta? tipo como digo ao app que deve procurar pelo arquivo com o nome da imagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como recomendado pelo amigo Paulo Rodrigo, o caminho das pastas podem ser alterados conforme atualizações no App. Podendo não ser encontrado.

Então realizei alterações somente para armazenar o nome da imagem no Core Data, e para recuperar esta imagem, executo o seguinte código:

```
    NSArray* caminhos = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* pastaDeDocumentos = [caminhos objectAtIndex:0];
    NSManagedObject *dadosCoreData = [dadosRetornadosDoCoreData objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* stringPathImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",pastaDeDocumentos,[dadosCoreData valueForKey:@"imagempath"]];
    UIImage* imageNew = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:stringPathImage];
```